# What's the 'environment' task in Rake?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

According to "[Custom Rake Tasks](http://railscasts.com/episodes/66-custom-rake-tasks)":

```
desc "Pick a random user as the winner"
task :winner => :environment do
  puts "Winner: #{pick(User).name}"
end
```

As far as I know, the `:winner => :environment` means "do `environment` before `winner`". But what's `environment`? When should I use it?

I tried `rake -T`, but in the list I couldn't find `environment`.

Comment: Check out the new syntax http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12493337/rake-aborted-undefined-method-map-for-namesymbol

Answer (score 151, accepted):

You can get access to your models, and in fact, your whole environment by making tasks dependent on the environment task. This lets you do things like `run rake RAILS_ENV=staging db:migrate`.

See "[Custom Rake Tasks](http://railscasts.com/episodes/66-custom-rake-tasks)".

Comment: Where is it defined in the source?  I found where the rake tasks are, and I found an empty task definition that depends on 'app:environment', but I can't find the definition of the app:environment task.  https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/tasks/engine.rake

Comment: @odigity Looks like here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.4/railties/lib/rails/application.rb#L454

Comment: Guess what chagpt can' answer this

Answer (score 51):

It loads in your Rails environment so you can actually use your models and what not. Otherwise, it has no idea about those things.

So if you made a task that just did `puts "HI!"` then you don't need to add the `:environment` task to the dependencies. But if you wish to do something like `User.find(1)` well that will need it.

Answer (score 50):

Including `=> :environment` will tell Rake to load full the application environment, giving the relevant task access to things like classes, helpers, etc. Without the `:environment`, you won't have access to any of those extras.

Also `=> :environment` itself does not make available any environment-related variables, e.g. `environment`, `@environment`, `RAILS_ENV`, etc.

Comment: The method of task's document is too simple to understand it.