# How to fix "uninitialized constant" in a Rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rake, rake-task

I have a problem when I do:

```
namespace :xaaron do
  task :get_roles do
    roles = Xaaron::Role.all
    puts roles
  end
  
  task :get_role, [:name] do |t, args|
    role = Xaaron::Role.find(args[:name].parameterize)
    puts role
  end
end
```

The first task will work fine. I can even add `binding.pry` and run `Xaaron::Role` and get information about Roles back. But the second task fails with:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Xaaron::Role
```

I run each task in my main app because these tasks are inside an engine, using:

```
bin/rake xaaron:get_roles` and `bin/rake xaaron:get_role
```

I can run `bin/rails c` in the main application that uses the engine and run `Xaaron::Role` and get information about Roles table.

Why is the second one failing but the first one is not? Is there scoping with arguments?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I'm not sure why either works, but if this is Rails and those are Rails models, your tasks should depend on the environment:

```
task :get_roles => [ :environment ] do
```

By depending on the `:environment` task, it first loads Rails.

Also see: [What's the 'environment' task in Rake?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7044714/).

Comment: obviously it rails and I think it loads the default environment. Be it development or production or what ever. But ill give what you say a try based on votes to your answer.

Comment: You also cannot do task `:something => [:enviroment], [:param] do |t, args| ... end` with your "example" can you clarify how I might pass in arguments?

Comment: try `:something, [:param] => [:environment]`

Answer (score 13):

You can also run a Rake task as

```
bundle exec rake environment xaaron:get_role
```

This will load the Rails environment first.

Comment: This is what worked for me. Not sure why you got downvoted

Comment: Yep, @coisnepe. Deserves a 1+. :)

Comment: do you literally type in the word "environment" or are you meant to substitute that in. e.g: `bundle exec rake production xaaron:get_role`?

Answer (score 1):

I kept getting uninitialized constant errors for a Rake task, even after depending on `:environment` and running with `bundle exec`.

The issue was that I was making a `Rake::TestTask` and, even though the Rake task had access to all constants, the test files themselves did not have access to constants.

The solution was to add this line to the top of my test file:

```rb
require_relative '../config/environment'
```

This is the Rake task:

```rb
require "rake/testtask"

Rake::TestTask.new(:test) do |t|
  t.libs << "test"
  t.libs << "lib"
  t.test_files = FileList["test/**/test_*.rb"]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To add, as of **Ruby 1.9** and above, you can use this hash syntax:

```
namespace :xaaron do
  desc "Rake task to get roles"
  task get_roles: :environment do
    roles = Xaaron::Role.all
    puts roles
  end
  #####

end
```

And then you can run the command below to run the Rake task:

```
rake xaaron:get_roles
```

or

```
bundle exec rake xaaron:get_roles
```

Answer (score 0):

> config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)

in application.rb that work for me

Comment: Answers are not here to say thanks. Once you earn enough reputation you will be able to leave comments

Comment: @ShadowCrafter_01: It's not clear to me what answer this is thanking. It appears to be a new answer.