# Rails error Uninitialized constant importing csv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake-task, rakefile

This is my first time importing a csv file to my rails app.

I have the code below in /lib/tasks/import.rake

```
    require 'csv'
        CSV.foreach("lib/articles.csv", headers: true, encoding: "ISO8859-1") do |row|
            Article.new(title: row["Title"], body: row["Body"], user: User.find(1))
    end
```

When I run `rake import:articles`

I get this error:

```
     NameError: uninitialized constant Article
    /Users/justinMgrant/code/hrsurvival/lib/tasks/import.rake:8:in `block in <top (required)>'
    /Users/justinMgrant/code/hrsurvival/lib/tasks/import.rake:7:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/justinMgrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:658:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
    /Users/justinMgrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:658:in `each'
    /Users/justinMgrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:658:in `run_tasks_blocks'
    /Users/justinMgrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:452:in `run_tasks_blocks'
    /Users/justinMgrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:453:in `load_tasks'
    /Users/justinMgrant/code/hrsurvival/Rakefile:6:in `<top (required)>'
    (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Any idea what I’m doing wrong?

Comment: Add the complete rake task please. I'm guessing that you are not using   `task :taskname => :environment` which creates the rake task in the context of your Rails environment. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044714/whats-the-environment-task-in-rake

Comment: That's what I have in the rake task, but when I add `task articles: :environment`  this error appears `Don't know how to build task 'import:articles' (see --tasks)`

Comment: That's the entirety of your rake file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not actually defining your task in your rakefile. This should work for you to be able to run `rake import:articles`.

```
namespace :import do

  desc 'An optional description for what the task does'
  task :articles => :environment do
    # your code goes here
  end

end
```

`rake import:articles` is saying to look for a task called `articles` within a namespace called `import`, which is why the namespace is necessary for what you're currently trying.

And as @max mentioned, utilizing `task :articles => :environment` is what tells the task to run in the context of your Rails environment, which would make your `Articles` model and any other model available to you in that task.